# Angular JS Directive not rendering inline style in IE9

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive that is working fine in Chrome, but in IE9 it renders '{{myappInitials.IconColor}' into the HTML:

```
<tr ng-repeat="person in data.people">
    <td class="text-left">
       <div myapp-initials="person" ></div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

The directive:

```
angular.module('myapp.directives', [])
    .directive('myappInitials', function () {
       return {
          restrict: 'A',
          template: "<div style='background-color:{{myappInitials.IconColor}}' class='userIconMedium'>{{myappInitials.Firstname.charAt(0) + ' ' + myappInitials.Surname.charAt(0)}}</div>",
          scope: {
             myappInitials: "="
          }
  };
});
```

There is a [Plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/h7f3z2kZpUEvIMEX7zOg?p=preview) to check.

Is this an Angular bug?

Comment: I cant really test this on IE9 but Have you tried using `ng-class` ?

Comment: You can also use `ng-style`

Comment: It doesn't make any difference changing the `style` tag to `ng-style` in this example.

Comment: replace `style` with `ng-attr-style`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IE (including 11) does not support interpolation in style attributes. You must use ngStyle for that, e.g
ng-style="{'background-color': myAppInitials.IconColor}"

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie

This is my working solution, though I'd prefer to include the ng-style element within the template of the directive but I am not yet sure whether this is possible:

```
<tr ng-repeat="person in data.people">
    <td class="text-left">
       <div ng-style="{'background-color':person.IconColor}" class="userIconMedium" myapp-initials="person"></div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

The directive:

```
angular.module('myapp.directives', [])
    .directive('myappInitials', function () {
       return {
          restrict: 'A',
          template: "{{myappInitials.Firstname.charAt(0) + ' ' + myappInitials.Surname.charAt(0)}}",
          scope: {
             myappInitials: "="
          }
};
 });
```